# How to edit Windows 7 Selection menu on DVD

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

I have downloaded one Windows 7 ISO from Internet.

At installation i got menu "Select the Operating System you want to install"

While choose, It displays some name one name in description of choose operating system.

I would like to add my name here. How can i do it ?

Here the screen shot of Windows 7 selection menu, I have downloaded,

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the ISO, or what it says when you boot up?

Comment: @soandos here i've added screen shot. check it., need to change "Made by Mr.Black.Share10s.Com"

Answer (score 1):

The list is produced by the setup app. Like all recent Microsoft applications, this application is digitally signed. Since you do not own the Microsoft key, you cannot alter the application and re-sign it.

Comment: I want to know how it possible to edit ? I saw like this many places. How they did it ? Which file have those details ?